# What does the phrase "I could care less," really mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What does the phrase "I could care less," really mean? When I look at it I think that it refers to an expression of indifference, but many people use it when they're implying that they don't care. I've never been quite sure about this and wanted to know if anyone knows the original meaning of the phrase. Thank you!

Comment: The phrase I know is "I could *not* care less". I don't understand why people say your version. Unless there is an implied "....but it isn't likely."

Comment: @WeatherVane - because kids copy what their friends are saying and it just snowballs.  All the kids said it when I was growing up.  Even today I have to stop and think “which one is it?”

Comment: As a native New Yorker, I can attest to the sarcasm: Like I could care even less! (I couldn't.) Compare *I could give a rat's ass!* which conveys that I couldn't offer even that much concern (= I couldn't give a rat's ass!)

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/could-couldnt-care-less

Comment: [Probable and Certain Duplicates](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=could+care+less) include [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/706), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/475277), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/278637), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/187037), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/283149), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/527681), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/47294), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/290921), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/555196).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an informal version, mainly used in AmE

***[I could care less](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/could-care-less)***
(phrase US informal)(also *I couldn't care less*)

> used to emphasize rudely that you are not interested in or worried about something or someone.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

It's an example of "[Negation by Association](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/%7Emyl/languagelog/archives/001202.html)", as I once called it [in print](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/AmpleNegatives.pdf).
The French negative particle *pas*  is normally preceded by the overt negative *ne*,

- *Je ne sais pas.* "I don't know"

with both words together officially  conveying negation; but *pas* (which originally meant 'step; bit') is often used for negation all by itself, having gained a negative flavor by being in the same sentences with *ne* so often. It's sort of like eating a lot of garlic.

- *Pas de fumer* "No smoking".

*Could care less* is similarly imbued with a negative flavor, as is *could give a damn/a shit*,
all of which are NPIs.

- *I could care less (about X)* = "I don't care (about X)"
- *I could give a damn (about X)* = "I don't care (about X)"

Note that these English negative idioms are all associated with the English verb *care*, and with the English modal *could*. It is perhaps not surprising that a modal is involved with a set of negative idioms. Modals match with negatives like  rice matches with vegetables.

Comment: Us East-pondians really don't understand what West-pondians are angling at when they say "I could give a damn/care less" (or at least the first few times for each). Hasn't reached over here yet, properly and still kicks me in the funny bone. Do you know of any such negation by association examples (that also occur) in BrE?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. *Frankly, my dear, I do give a damn.* That sort of thing is as confusing to me as it is to you folks. I don't recall ever hearing it when I was myself a child some threescore years ago, and I seem to’ve held too little converse with later generations’ children to notice this solecism cropping and creeping up on me.

Comment: It's just what I grew up listening to. You want weird? I also grew up listening to [_So don't I_](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/so-dont-i), which is also mentioned in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

It's a misspoken way of saying "I don't care."

The correct expression is "I could NOT care less." That is an exclamation that exaggerates "I don't care" into "I care not at all", "I could not care less than nothing", etc.

"I could care less" is lazy and incorrect. Unless someone is trying to be clever and saying "I care a little bit more than nothing."

Comment: It is a mis-speak, though it's now so common that it's accepted as correct, even by dictionary makers.